# Up and down key is not working autocomplete while seleting

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete with multi-dimensional array but when selecting by up or down key is not working.

for example when i am using up and down key on then it auto despaired and note selecting item

here is my code

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.location', function(e) {
  $(this).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: url,
    focus: function( event, ui ) {
      if (mode == 'flight') {
        $(this).val( ui.item.fullname );
      }
      else{
        $(this).val( ui.item.name );
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      if (mode == 'flight') {
        $(this).val( ui.item.fullname )
                .attr('data-match', ui.item.fullname)
                  .attr('data-code', ui.item.airport_code);
      }
      else{
        $(this).val( ui.item.name )
                .attr('data-code', ui.item.code)
                  .attr('data-match', ui.item.name);
      }

      $(this).removeClass('inctv')
              .removeClass('border-red');

      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  })
  .autocomplete().data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem =  function( ul, item ) {
    var newName = mode == 'flight' ? item.fullname : item.name;

    return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + newName + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
  };

});
```

i have no idea where i am doing wrong.

Comment: is there any related Html too ?

Comment: And what could the URL be ??

Comment: it is stored in url variable and return a json `[{code:"...", name:"..."}]`